# How to put ® in superscript?

Tags: javascript, css, unicode

I tried to put ® behind a brand in MySQL data, let's say Apple®. In code it is superscript, but when it displays to HTML, it becomes normal.

I want to display it in superscript in HTML. How can I do that? CSS? JS? Or Is there any unicode that displays text in superscript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
Apple<sup>&reg;</sup>
```

Comment: that is using html code, but I have a lots of data "brands" in database, how to I do that using AJAX?

Comment: @P.Lau How AJAX relates to your question? I showed you the way to make the special character superscript. You can e.g. replace in the data got from the DB all occurrences of `®` with `<sup>&reg;</sup>`

Comment: all the brand name in mysql table has been appended with ®, but it always display in normal when ajax return and display in html